# How do I make Crystal Reports work with newer versions of Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have been using Visual Studio 2012 and tried to add a Crystal Report to my website, but it doesn't work. Then I installed Visual Studio 2010, and it worked fine. I have tried to test Crystal Reports with Visual Studio 2012 and 2015 on other computers, but it doesn't work.

What is wrong with these products? Please can anyone shed light on this question?

Comment: Do you have more information? But one thing I could think of that, Crystal dll's have different versions for different .Net Frameworks, maybe you have to choose the right combination. Could you share any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you need to install an updated driver for your newer version of Visual Studio. The available versions are on the "[Crystal Reports, Developer for Visual Studio Downloads](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads)" wiki page.

Note that it tells you which service pack applies to each Visual Studio version.

> To integrate "SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio" **you must run the Install Executable**. Running the MSI will not fully integrate Crystal Reports into VS. **MSI files by definition are for runtime distribution only**.

Since they also say the updates are cumulative, you *should* be able to just install the latest and have it work in all current versions.

> All Service Packs are cumulative so we are removing the links to previous patches and will be keeping 3 or 4 still active. Links still work if you have them.